# TypeScript: interface polymorphism issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a base *Account* interface:

```js
interface Account {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  type: AccountType;
}
```

where *AccountType*:

```js
enum AccountType {
  Foo = 'foo',
  Bar = 'bar'
}
```

and two account subtypes (*FooAccount* and *BarAccount*) that extend the *Account* interface:

```js
interface FooAccount extends Account {
  foo: Foo;
}
```

```js
interface BarAccount extends Account {
  bar: Bar;
}
```

*Account* is an aggregate that holds basic account info and, depending on the type, owns a *Foo* or a *Bar* object.

Actions on these objects, can only be performed by their owners (the account).

I have defined an *AccountRepository*:

```js
export interface AccountRepository {
  findById(accountId: number): Account;
}
```

where the `findById(accountId: number)` returns an *Account*, but this account could be any *FooAccount* or *BarAccount*.

I want to use this `findById` function before performing any action on a `Foo` or `Bar`. For example, let's say I want to update an account's `Foo`:

- would use `findById(accountId: number)` to retrieve the account
- check the AccountType of the account, in this case `account.type === AccountType.Foo`
- if the AccountType check is correct, then would access `account.foo.id` and use that `fooId` to perform the desired update

The problem here is, that this last point is failing: as `findById(accountId: number): Account` returns an *Account* and there is no `foo: Foo` property defined in its interface.

I have also tried the following, but cannot be done either:

`const fooAccount: FooAccount = findById(accountId);`

because the function returns an *Account*.

I am trying to figure out how can this be achieved, what am I missing out? Is there anything I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved this using **Type Assertion**, by just adding `as FooAccount` like this:

`const fooAccount: FooAccount = findById(accountId) as FooAccount;`

There's no need to modify the existing design to achieve it.

> Basically, the assertion from type S to T succeeds if either S is a subtype of T or T is a subtype of S.

***More info:*** https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is probably to use a discriminated union.

```
export class Bar { public idBar: number; }
class Foo { public idFoo: number; }
interface AccountCommon {
  id: number;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

enum AccountType {
  Foo = 'foo',
  Bar = 'bar'
}

interface FooAccount extends AccountCommon {
  type: AccountType.Foo; // type can only be Foo
  foo: Foo;
}
interface BarAccount extends AccountCommon {
  type: AccountType.Bar; // type can only be Bar
  bar: Bar;
}
// The discriminated union
type Account = BarAccount | FooAccount //type is common so type can be either Foo or Bar

export interface AccountRepository {
  findById(accountId: number): Account;
}

let r: AccountRepository;

let a = r.findById(0);
if (a.type === AccountType.Bar) { // type guard
  a.bar.idBar // a is now BarAccount
} else {
  a.foo.idFoo // a is now FooAccount
}
```

Comment: Link to the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: this is not a polymorphism at all