# How to add property/attribute to typescript interface depends on other attributes values?

Tags: angular, typescript

I like to add property in interface depends on other attribute value. For example I have an interface `interface TemplateConfig`

```
export interface TemplateConfig {
  mode : Mode;
  templateName : string;
  templateFilter: TemplateFilter
}

export enum Mode {
  DYNAMIC = "DYNAMIC",
  STATIC="STATIC",
}
```

I like to add condition in this inerface, if I have property `mode = Mode.DYNAMIC` so remove the other property `templateName` from the interface.

Comment: E.g see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608124/typescript-interface-polymorphism-issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: interface polymorphism issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608124/typescript-interface-polymorphism-issue)